# How to change csv file delimiter

Tags: csv, awk

here's a csv file items.txt

```
item-number,item-description,item-category,cost,quantity-available
```

I tried to change the field separator from `,` to `\n` using `awk` and I need a easy way to do it.

1) this command does not work

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print}' items.txt
```

2) this command works, but the real csv i need to process has 15+ columns, i dont want to provide all columns variables

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $1,$2}' items.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. After setting the `OFS` to newline, you will need to re-construct the fields to get them separated to newlines.

`$1=$1` re-evaluates the fields and separates them by `OFS` which by default is space. Since we set the `OFS` to `RS` which by default is new line, you get the desired output.

The `1` at the end of statement is idiomatic way of saying print the line.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=RS}{$1=$1}1' file
item-number
item-description
item-category
cost
quantity-available
```

Answer (score 3):

If your fields do not contain `,`'s, you may use `tr`:

```
tr ',' '\n' < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get awk to re-evaluate the string by changing a field.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {$1 = $1; print}' items.txt
```

Or, if you're sure the first column is always non-empty and nonzero, you could use the somewhat simpler:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} $1 = $1' items.txt
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I gave the check mark to @JS웃 because the explanation of `$1=$1`

Comment: `$1 = $1` sets a field, which forces awk to rebuild the line (using OFS) like I said in the first sentence. In the second example, it also serves as the condition, printing the line if `$1` is true (i.e. nonzero and non-empty).